# Как написать батник который определяет в какой папке путь к файлу и записать путь файл!

Tags: c#, администрирование, bat

Я пытался написать я не разбираюсь в системном программирование.
Я хочу получить путь каталога где лежит файл с базой данных и записать каталог файл потом с# использовать как подключение бд.

```
 @echo Off
    SET  path=%cd%
    echo %path% >> %path%\pcc.txt
    pause
```

Comment: Прошу вас расписать вопрос подробнее и написать про сам вопрос хоть что-то кроме заголовка. Написанное неоднозначно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я написал скрипт он не идеален  находит путь в каталоги  в котором его запустили записывает в файл путь к файлу.

```
 @echo Off
SET  path=%cd%
echo %path%
@echo %path% > E:\pcc.txt
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Если необходимо получить путь к запущенному файлу, то достаточно

```
echo %cd% >> pcc.txt
```

Если же необходимо найти путь к файлу, который указывается как аргумент (например cd.bat C:\file1.txt) то можно написать так

```
echo %~dp1 >> pcc.txt
```

Comment: У меня есть в пути русские слова мне выдает Кракозябры как исправить?